# PosRegEnable - How to change motor parameters?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, programming, nxc

I want to set PID parameters for a faster 'attack' when using PosRegEnablePID() on a motor. I am compiling with nbc/nxc 1.2.1 r4 mac osx fatbinary using -Z2 and -EF flags.

But the compiler says:

`# Error: Undefined Identifier PosRegEnablePID`

How can I set PID parameters for PosReg?

```
PosRegEnable(OUT_A);
```

compiles just fine...

Comment: I know that the website says it is only for older versions, but have you tried `posreg.h`?

Comment: Also, would you mind posting your sample code?

Comment: I've closed this question because without further information it doesn't appear to be resolvable.